# Extract specific subfolder from Zip

Tags: c#

I have a zip file where in the root, contains only two folders: `Binaries` and `Source` But i only need the Binaries folder. Have is this possible in C#?
This is the code i have currently, but is not working.

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath.FullName))
{
     foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
     {
        if (entry.FullName.StartsWith(@"Binaries/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
             entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(extractPath, "Hepper"));
        }
     }
}
```

**UPDATE:** 
It gives me this error The file

> 'C:\Hepper\Hepper' already exists.

Comment: "not working" is no error description. Please be more precise: Do you get an exception? Compiler error? Unexpected result? If any of those, provide details - Error message, actual vs expected output etc.

Comment: Do you wish to extract the content of the binaries folder in a folder called hepper? Or place the whole binaries folder in a folder called hepper?

Comment: @CasperThuleHansen Yes. I want to extract the hole Binaries folder into the Hepper folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an solution to my problem:

```
using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zip1 = Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read(path.FullName))
{
       var selection = (from e in zip1.Entries
                      where (e.FileName).StartsWith("Binaries/")
                                 select e);


     Directory.CreateDirectory(_localExtratingPath.FullName);

     foreach (var e in selection)
     {
         e.Extract(_localExtratingPath.FullName);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At a glance (without actually checkin the API) it looks like you are trying to extract all entries to the same filename (`Path.Combine(extractPath, "Hepper")`). You'd probably want to have the path and filename from the `entry` as part of where you are extracting to.